# How to test if humidity meter works

Tags: home, temperature

I bought a digital humidity meter and it reads between 55%-65% everywhere in my house. It's surprising that it's this high. Is there anyway I can verify it is working accurately? Even if I bought a second one and the readings were different, I still wouldn't know which one was right.

What I'm actually trying to do is find out why something is causing me intangible discomfort in the environment in the house.

Answer (score 1):

Most inexpensive relative humidity (RH) meters are *very slow* to respond, and many are not very accurate. What should be the most important observation is *how you feel* on days when the RH is high or low.

[You can make your own *hair hygrometer*](https://www.exploratorium.edu/exploring/hair/hair_activity.html) [quite easily](http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/Weather_p010.shtml#summary), and this will respond to RH more rapidly and more reliably than the "store-bought" [Metal-paper coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygrometer#Metal-paper_coil_type) type variety.

Comment: The diy wouldn't work for me as no one in my house hold has a hairdryer. However, I did find that inexpensive humidity meters exists ($4) so buying a couple and returning them to the store is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Get a plastic bottle and put an inch of table salt in the bottom. Keep adding water till the salt is fully covered.

I'm not sure what your probe looks like. If it's a thick air sensor wrap plumbing tape (Teflon tape around the neck and wedge it in the mouth of the bottle. If it's the metal needle type, stab it into the bottle near the mouth.

With the bottle sealed it should read around 75-78%. Just leave it somewhere temperature stable for a couple hours and check on it.

There are other "humidity salts" for different RH. [See here for measurement ranges](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/salt-humidity-d_1887.html)